# Cassandra 2.1 changing snitch from EC2Snitch to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

Currently we have used EC2Snitch using two AZs in a single AWS region. The goal was to provide resiliency even when one AZ is not available. Most data are replicated with RF=2, so each AZ gets a copy based on Ec2Snitch.

Now we have come to a conclusion to move to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch. Reason primarily is that we have realized that one AZ going down is a remote occurrence and even if it happens, there are other systems in our stack that don't support this; so eventually whole app goes down if that happens.

Other reason is that with EC2Snitch and two AZs, we had to scale in factor of 2 (one in each AZ). With GossipingPropertyFileSnitch using just one rack, we can scale in factor of 1.

When we change this snitch setting, will the topology change? I want to avoid having a need to run nodetool repair. We always had failures with running nodetool repair and it runs forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the topology changes depends on how you carry out the change. If you assign the same logical dc and rack to the node as what it's currently configured to, you shouldn't get a topology change.

You have to match the rack to the AZ after updating to `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`. You need to do a rolling restart for the re-configuration to take place.

Example `cassandra-rackdc.properties` for 2 nodes in 1 dc across 2 AZs:

```sh
# node=10.0.0.1, dc=first, AZ=1
dc_suffix=first
# Becomes
dc=first
rack=1

# node=10.0.0.2, dc=first, AZ=2
dc_suffix=first
# Becomes
dc=first
rack=2
```

On a side note you need to explore why repairs are failing. Unfortunately they are very important for cluster health.

Comment: My cluster is distributed across two AZs of a single DC. So with EC2Snitch, it would map to one DC and two rack. I am planning to move single rack using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch. Then the procedure would be 1. retain existing rack-dc combination 2. Change the DC from 2 to 1 on the second AZ nodes and run nodetool repair. Should the repair be run on every node change? That is going to take a lot of time.

Comment: You’d have to do a full repair yes. Take a look at [Cassandra reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/) it allows you to carry out a subrange repair which uses up less resources as it’s a more granular procedure.

Comment: Can I run a local repair after Changing config in each node?

Comment: You stated before that you have problems repairing, without taking look at your cluster I'm afraid I can't give a correct answer to that question, but it would be a starting point to try repairing the cluster, one node at a time (make sure a repair completes before triggering it on another node).